get inertia matrix in urdf
I have the inertial parameters of the links for a urdf file but my teacher asked me if the inertia matrix is weightless in a urdf file. Right know I inserted the parameters with the mass (kg*m^2).
I took the inertia moments at the center of mass. Is this good cause I get really big torques.
So do I need to divide the inertia moments by the mass to insert them in a urdf?

The SI units of inertia are $kg * m ^2$ we use SI by default. The values are just the inertia tensor.
The mass of the object is represented separately, but is inherent to the inertia.
There is a larger formulation possible which can include both mass and inertia in one matrix. The Spacial Mass Matrix but that's completely different. https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__multibody__spatial__inertia.html
